# Recover changes made after checkout

Tags: linux, git

I made a checkout to the previous commit and all local changes (neither staged nor commited) were gone. Is there a way to recover those local changes?

Comment: Please clarify. Do you mean that you had unstaged/uncommitted local changes, and that they are now gone as a result of checking out an older commit? I'm asking because Git normally prevents you from checking out stuff that would overwrite local changes...

Comment: Generally, there is no way to recover files that have not been staged or committed with git.

Comment: I did checkout -f I believe and then, as I understand, all files went to the versions they were in that commit. Any help?

Comment: Nope. If you overwrite a file contents that git does not know about (the `-f` option does that), that content's a goner.

Comment: Got it. But I still went back to those changes in the editor I use just hitting Ctrl+Z for each and every file.

Comment: @SergeyIvanov So, is your problem solved? If so, you got lucky, there. If you had closed your editor, you would probably have irremediably lost all local changes. Generally speaking, you should think twice before using the `-f` switch in a Git command.

Comment: Typically without the "-f", git will warn you about your local changes and recommend that you use git stash.

Answer (score 1):

Sergey - there are only a handful of commands that can nuke your working directory changes.  `git checkout -f` is one of them (`git reset --hard` is another).  I would not recommend you ever use that form as your default.  Use `git checkout` instead.  If that fails (which it will if you have changes), then use `git status` and `git diff` to look at the changes you have, and either save them off (commit or stash), or explicitly throw them out.